# Оболочка с модулями Android

Tags: java, android, модули

Стоит задача написать приложение в которое будет заходить юзер под логин\пароль и внутри приложения в зависимости от прав которые у него есть отображаются модули(кожный модуль отдельное приложение которое без оболочки не работает).Я знаю, как связывать проекты, добавляя модули.
Но вопрос в другом.Для примера:
у нас есть оболочка (BaseProjct) внутри которого есть возможность выбрать в какое именно приложение нужно перейти в зависимости от прав юзера. но таких модулей может быть много 5-8 и это никак не связанные между собой проекты и будут весить прилично , а для определенных юзеров нужны только 1-2.
Как реализовать подгрузку модуля в уже скомпилированую апк. что бы не обновлять BaseProjct когда обновляется какой то модуль(такое будет часто)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как раз на Google IO на прошлой неделе рассказывали о новой фиче, появится в Android Studio 3.2 (Уже доступна в Canary channel).

> Dynamic feature modules

По сути, приложение можно будет разбить на модули, которые обозначаются атрибутом `dist:onDemand="true"` и они будут загружаться по требованию.

Для вашего случая может быть подходящее решение. Документация:
https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/configure#dynamic_feature_modules

Answer (score 0):

Единственное что впомнил это статья на [хакере](https://xakep.ru/2016/06/02/android-plugins-binder/) про плагины, но раздел платный.